# dynamic development with firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am following a toolbar tutorial for firefox and i am unable to develop dynamically. I have changed the "install.rdf" file names with the .com and without the ".com". I have created a separate development profile as well. I created a text file with matching names in the  tag. The text file contents had the absolute path of the folder. i placed it into the extension folder which is located in the profile. I started firefox but nothing happened. Noh toolbar was displayed. Can anybody help?
The link of the tutorial i am following is http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/toolbar-tutorial/chapter-4/
I cannot move forward without getting this working

Comment: Have you downloaded the sample toolbar extension that the tutorial offers and compared it with your code? That might give you a clue as to what piece of the puzzle you're missing. Also, make sure you "installed" your extension into the appropriate profile folder (and make sure you are launching Firefox using the correct profile).